# $or query in mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I already have this document at the db:

```
    > db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fd349242b153bfbd95a15a8"), "nombre" : "Javier", "apellido" : "Roger" }
```

Now I execute this query:

```
db.test.find({"nombre": "Javier"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fd349242b153bfbd95a15a8"), "nombre" : "Javier", "apellido" : "Roger" }
```

It works as spected.

But when I execute this query, mongodb is not returning any results:

```
db.test.find({$or:[{"nombre": "Javier"}, {"apellido": "Javier"}]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I insert that document your syntax works for me.

`$or` was new in MongoDB v1.6. Is it possible you're running a really old version?

Comment: That's it. I was running version 1.2.2. Thanks noa!